# Why do we require that the interaction density be built out of fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In p.191, Chapter 5 of Weinberg's QFT, he is arguing about the inevitability of the quantum fields from Lorentz-invariance and cluster decomposition principles. He says

> The S-matrix will be Lorentz-invariant if the interaction can be written as
> $$
> V(t)=\int d^{3} x \mathscr{H}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t})
> $$
> where $\mathscr{H}$ is a scalar and satisfies the additional condition:
> $$
> \left[\mathscr{H}(x), \mathscr{H}\left(x^{\prime}\right)\right]=0 \quad \text { for } \quad\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)^{2} \geq 0
> $$
> ...

> In order to facilitate also satisfying the cluster decomposition principle we are going to construct $\mathscr{H} (x)$ out of creation and annihilation operators, but here we face a problem: as shown by
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> U_{0}(\Lambda, \alpha) a^{\dagger}(\mathrm{p} \sigma n) U_{0}^{-1}(\Lambda, \alpha)=& e^{-i(\Lambda p) \cdot \alpha} \sqrt{(\Lambda p)^{0} / p^{0}} \\
> & \times \sum_{\bar{\sigma}} D_{\bar{\sigma} \sigma}^{(j)}(W(\Lambda, p)) a^{\dagger}\left(\mathbf{p}_{\Lambda} \sigma n\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> under Lorentz transformations each such operators is multiplied by a matrix that depends on the momentum carried by that operator. How can we couple such operators together to make a scalar?
> The solution is to build $\mathscr{H} (x)$ out of $fields$, both annihilation fields $\psi_{l}^{+}(x)$ and creation fields $\psi_{l}^{-}(x)$
> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> \psi_{\ell}^{+}(x)=\sum_{\sigma n} \int d^{3} p u_{\ell}(x ; \mathbf{p}, \sigma, n) a(\mathbf{p}, \sigma, n) \\
> \psi_{\ell}^{-}(x)=\sum_{\sigma n} \int d^{3} p v_{\ell}(x ; \mathbf{p}, \sigma, n) a^{\dagger}(\mathbf{p}, \sigma, n)
> \end{array}
> $$

now my question is: how do we get the conclusion that building $\mathscr{H} (x)$ out of $fields$ is a necessary result in a clear way? Or in other words, is there some other way to build $\mathscr{H} (x)$ without fields that still satisfying the cluster decomposition principle?